# excel vba unload.me does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to close a userform with the unload.me command and suddenly I am getting an error message compile error argument not optional. i have look on your site but don't see any answers why suddenly it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Excel are you using?
My quick test in Excel 2016 shows it wants

`Unload Me`

(without the dot)

If that doesn't work, let us know...